# Why aren't the Server and X-Powered-By headers being removed?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, http-headers, global-asax

My ASP.NET 4.5 app is being deployed to shared hosting so I do not have access to IIS settings. To remove the `X-Powered-By` header, I specify in `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

And to remove the `Server` header, I specify in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```

However, responses still contain both headers:

```html
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:deflate
Content-Length:672
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 06 Jan 2013 00:41:20 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: Is that not an IIS Setting?

Comment: You may have to write a custom HttpModule to do this for you - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751644/azure-webrole-excesive-headers)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. But doesn't that `HttpModule` just do the same as my method in `Global.asax`?

Comment: Your absolutely right mate, I skimmed over that part of your code, see my answer

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why your `X-Powered-By` isn't being removed, but a Windows Update patch earlier this year made it so that the `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` fix no longer removed the `Server:` header for us.

We had to add a section to our `system.webServer` block (in the Web.config) using [IIS URL Rewrite Module 2](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-url-rewrite-module-20):

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" value=""/>
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `X-Powered-By:ASP.NET` is normally removed by simple web.config configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
...
```

The `ARR` one is unaffected by this configuration, it has to be removed through the IIS Manager, Editor configuration on the IIS root (not on a site): go to `system.webServer/proxy` node and set `arrResponseHeader` to `false`. After an `IISReset`, it is taken into account.
I have found this one [here](https://forums.iis.net/post/2019758.aspx), excepted this post is about old IIS 6.0 way of configuring things.

So for your case, without access to IIS settings, you would have to ask the server owner to adjust his configuration. Or try the [Url Rewrite solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543511/1178314) but of course, with `HTTP_X_Powered_By` server variable. It will at best only blank out the header, and I have not checked it works for the ARR case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 7 setting the [DisableMvcResponseHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler.disablemvcresponseheader%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property to true in the Global.asax should remove the "X-Powered-By" header

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
}
```

Comment: Hmm that is weird because it should work for IIS 7. Have you tried using the http module example I linked to?

Comment: Not at my dev machine at the moment, will try when I can. Thanks.

Comment: This one is for `X-AspNetMvc-Version` header, not for `X-Powered-By`. I have written an answer covering the different headers case I am aware of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17600445/1178314).

Answer (score 0):

Mostly server IIS doesn't allow us to remove server tags. You can try following code to achieve your goal.
Add in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Server", "");
 }
```

This code will remove your "X-AspNet-Version" and set Server value as blank.